# How can I create a matrix with the categories and values from several excel files in a folder

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have around 400 excel files in the form of a template with different values on each one but with the same format, example:
in a folder I have:

- person_1.xlsx
- person_2.xlsx
- person_3.xlsx
- ...

All person_#.xlsx are from a template, which it would look like this, in person_1.xlsx:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Carol | Hair color | Blonde |
| 2 | Sex | F |  |  |
| 3 | Age | 23 |  |  |
| 4 | Blood type | A+ |  |  |

What I want in the end is to compile a master file with the following format for example:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Name | Sex | Age | Hair color |
| 2 | person_1 | Carol | F |  |  |
| 3 | person_2 | Christian | M |  |  |
| 4 | person_3 | Laura | F |  |  |

Is there any easy way to do it in Python? Would appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you have headers and index in your excel files?

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should do  what you need.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

def reset_columns(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df.columns = pd.RangeIndex(df.columns.size)
    return df

def flatten_person_df(df):
    return pd.concat(
        reset_columns(df[df.columns[i:i+2]])
        for i in range(0, len(df.columns), 2)
    ).dropna(how="all").reset_index(drop=True)

def combine_files(directory):
    return pd.concat(
        flatten_person_df(pd.read_excel(f, header=None)).set_index(0).transpose().assign(filename=f)
        for f in Path(directory).glob("*.xlsx")
    )
```

You can call `combine_files` on the directory containing the files. For example,

```py
result = combine_files("./data/")
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific with the question. This is very close to what I need, but the category is not only in the first column, there are other categories in other columns, so I would need to access the cell positions individually,

Comment: @PabloLuz I've made a change that should work provided that the columns in your excel file alternate between key and value. (That is, "keys" like "Name," "Sex," and "Hair Color" are on the first, third, fifth, etc. column, and the "values" like "Carol," "F," and "Blonde" are on the second, fourth, sixth, etc. column.) If that's not always true, you will  probably be better off parsing the files using custom code with `openpyxl`.